# posting to Facebook error: '(#200) The user hasn\'t authorized the application to perform this action', type: 'OAuthException', code: 200

Tags: facebook, node.js, post

When i try to post something via facebook from my application i get the following error, the problem is that the application didn't ask for publish action permission
Here is the code

```
var access_token = 'access_token'
FB.setAccessToken(access_token);

var body = '2 4 6 8 8.5';
FB.api('me/feed', 'post',{ message: body, access_token:access_token}, function (res) {
if(!res || res.error) {
console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
return;
}
```

{ message: '(#200) The user hasn\'t authorized the application to perform this action',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 200 }

And i have another question 
whaat access token should be used 
the user's access token , the application access token or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the user to allow the publish_actions extended permission to allow your app to post to Facebook.

See the publishing section to the [me/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed#publish) reference: "A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts". The user needs to be prompted "are you ok for this app to post to Facebook" and accept for this access token to work.

Note that it's good practice to check the user's permissions **before** trying to publish, which you can check by looking at the `me/permissions` endpoint:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "installed", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "public_profile", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "publish_actions", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "user_friends", 
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get this data by running:

```
FB.api("/me/permissions", function (response) {
    // data here
});
```

To ask the user for the permission, you need to add "publish_actions" into the `scope` when running the `FB.login` dialog:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

Comment: I guess you are giving me the right answer but it seems that i'm still missing something
can you tell me how to make the user allow the publish_actions extended permission

Comment: I've updated the bottom of the answer to give you the code you need.

Comment: Is FB.login a standard function or API or you mean to put the scope in my login function ?

Comment: actually i don't have a login function i just make paassport authentication using these two functions
`app.get('/auth/facebook',
 passport.authenticate('facebook'),
 function(req, res){
 });
 app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
 passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '' }),
 function(req, res) {
 res.redirect('/account');
 });`

Comment: Read the permissions section here http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/. You want to use "scope".

Comment: Yeah this one worked for me 
Thanks a million 
Really thank You very much :)

Comment: Great, could you mark this as the correct answer so other in the community know how to solve this in the future? Cheers